# R Programming summarizing minimum and maximum for each value of an entity

Tags: r, group-by, max, min

I want to summarize and report a the minimum and maximum value of WW for each of the BOMs below.

```
BOM = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")

WW = c("201305","201306","201308","201310","201311","201345","201346","201347","201349","201352","201336","201337","201339","201341")

df <- data.frame(BOM,WW)
```

I attempt to do so below, but unfortunately I get a global minimum and maximum WW, not individual for each BOM as I want it.

```
df <- group_by(df, BOM)

extremes <- summarise(df, minw=min(as.numeric(WW)), maxw=max(as.numeric(WW)))
```

Can you help? 
Here is how exactly I expect the end up if the code was to work.

```
BOM= c("A","B","C")

minWW = c("201305","201345","201336")

maxWW = c("201311","201352","201341")

df2 <-data.frame(BOM,minWW,maxWW)
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: why do you build WW as character vector? or are they Dates?

Comment: You can check whether `plyr` is also loaded.  If that is the case use `dplyr::summarise(df, ....` should solve it (as function got masked)

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `WW` are numeric variables:

```
BOM = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")

# Next  time just remove "" around your varibales to import as numeric

WW = as.numeric(c("201305","201306","201308","201310","201311","201345","201346","201347","201349","201352","201336","201337","201339","201341"))


df <- data.frame(BOM,WW)
```

Use aggregate:

```
aggregate(WW ~ BOM, data = df, min)

  BOM     WW
1   A 201305
2   B 201345
3   C 201336

aggregate(WW ~ BOM, data = df, max)

  BOM     WW
1   A 201311
2   B 201352
3   C 201341
```

Comment: This accomplishes the summarization. Thanks all.